Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
I was using the app for last 6 months and there was no issue with singing using Google login.
now Im getting Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch. This is however only on one laptop. I can login to the app using Google login from another laptop and on my mobile.
Why do I get this error on one particular laptop which is the main laptop I was using for this app for last 6 months
